# Customize Navigation Bar in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller

I used Navigation Controller & navigation Bar in **StroryBoard**.

I want to customize navigation Bar for one view as follow for right side of navigation bar.

[image]

**My tried code**

```
    UIButton *btn_list=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn_list.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30);
    [btn_list setTitle:@"Liste" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_list setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red-left.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_list setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black-left.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    UIBarButtonItem *list_bar=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn_list];
    
    UIButton *btn_map=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    btn_map.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30);
    [btn_map setTitle:@"Karte" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_map setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"red-right.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn_list setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"black-right.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    UIBarButtonItem *map_bar=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithCustomView:btn_map];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:list_bar,map_bar, nil];
```

**Problem of tried code: There is a space between two buttons.**

**How can I achieve this?**

Comment: clarify me that u want to use a segment control as a barbuttonitem. am i right?

Comment: @sreekanthk, yes you are right

Comment: then y r u using two buttons instead of taking a UISegmentControl

Comment: but in Segment control I am not able to set custom image.:(

Comment: reduce ur image size man,

Answer (score 1):

Just use Segmented Control: you have a full example [HERE](http://www.makemegeek.com/uisegmentedcontrol-example-ios/)

Comment: but in Segment control I am not able to set custom image.:(

Comment: @user2893370 No, you can custom SegmentedControl check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21603822/ios-6-uisegmentedcontrol-with-ios-7-design  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18900034/use-ios-6-style-segmented-control-in-ios-7

Answer (score 1):

declare a segment control with custom view

`UISegmentedControl *control = (UISegmentedControl *) [segmentBarButton customView];`

and then add it to barbuttonitem view

`UIBarButtonItem *segmentBarButton=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:control];`

dont forget to write the lines that relates to segment control customized view like ur requirement adding red or black images to the segment 0 or 1.